# margin-top не работает

Tags: html, css, margin

margin-top не работает :(

```css
.text {
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#maintext {
text-decoration: none;
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <metacharset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <a title="Получить п%*(ы" id="maintext" class="text" href="kek.html.html">ыыы</a>
        <center/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто добавьте "блочности" ссылке:

```css
.text {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#maintext {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <metacharset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <a title="Получить п%*(ы" id="maintext" class="text" href="kek.html.html">ыыы</a>
    <center/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что ссылка это inline элемент